# Syfer (now Knowe) X2Y EMI filter

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

I struggled to compare the EMI filter needed for 24V to 5V non-isolated BUCK DC/DC (running 300KHz to 500KHz) to ensure it passes CE conformance. I wish to keep switching noise within the DC/DC area as well as filtering out external noise entering into DC/DC.

I have two choices: 
(a) Simple SMD ferrite beads and COG cap as pi filter
(b) SMD X2Y filter (1206J1000103MXTE03). It claims benefits superior to (a).

I have spoken to support and they have very little application note to demonstrate the benefits of the X2Y technology. No PPT presentation.
[image]
Has anyone use X2Y and how they compare with C-L-C pi filter.

Comment: I have just designed these in for a tech demo, well the Johanson's variant, Have a read of their application notes https://johansondielectrics.com/x2y-filter-decoupling-capacitors

Comment: I too have been wondering if anyone has any actual experience with this. They have a ton of data for motors, but not as much for EMI filtering.

Comment: These Caps have much better RF SRF ESR characteristics when used properly. What is the problem you want  to solve? Ripple ? how much?  Not a pun, but this is an undefined XY problem  Johanson's parts are same as my answer .  TY @JonRB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are not trivial or simple with mutual coupling , unknown source impedances, complex loads and variable Q resonance and anti resonance.

Your schematic is already a 9th order LPF and non of the ESL are included.

The 10nF part you selected has an [SRF of 100MHz](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/218/X2YDatasheet-1316268.pdf) and that is due to the ESL of about 1nH due to its small size. But if you add 0.5nH/mm traces that will lower the SRF and possibly react with all the other reactances.  Good or bad all depends what emissions you have and need to control.

[image]

This is not a solution but demonstrates a lossy ferrite bead and cap with a SRF and a lower PRF anti-resonant peak.  You must get s parameters & simulate or characterize your approved vendors and test with suitable test methods on your layout or experiment with other modelling tools such as Falstad's or using a scope with impulse testing using AC couple 50 ohm semi-rigid coax terminated at DSO with 50R.

[image]

For example here was a perfectly flat group delay Bessel filter destroyed by mismatching the load R.
[image]